# Is there any algorithm which satisfy given condition?

Tags: algorithm

Is there any algorithm which satisfy given condition?

Algorithm whose best case time complexity is **less than** average case time complexity and average case time complexity is **less than** worst case time complexity.

Comment: Looking up an element in an unsorted array on a random access machine. Now if you mean _asymptotic_ time complexity, then that answer isn't correct, and the problem is much more interesting. But I'm not going to spoil your fun.

Comment: Almost anything? If a teacher asked you this, he probably wants you to name one of the algorithms discussed in his class.

Comment: Hint: Any reason for specifically putting bold for "less than"? Do you mean that, it has to be asymptotically less than. e.g. O(n) < O(n log(n)) < O(n^2)?

Comment: @gene yes I am looking for asymptotic time complexity

Comment: @Yogi yes strictly lesser....

Comment: So, you must have got my hint. @m69 comment may also help.

Comment: Hint? Sorry I didn't get... This question is out of curiosity.... I didn't get anything on the web

Comment: OK. Could you mentions what all algorithms have you analysed to check if above condition holds true?

Comment: All basic sorting algorithms... some tree operations .... And implementation of stack and queue in different types .. but I have found either best or AVG are same or AVG and worst are same...

Comment: If you had mentioned in your question which algorithms you'd already considered and what your findings were, you could probably have avoided the downvotes.

Comment: Random algorithm:  best in worst, average and best case

Answer (score 0):

A weird question, given that best ≤ average ≤ worst is always true by definition.

Quicksort has the behaviors O(n) / O(n Log n) / O(n²). [Average case for equiprobable permutations.]

---

It is worth to note that *the* average case does not exist, because it depends on the statistical distribution of the data, which is independent of the algorithm. So the average case behaviors can range from the best case to the worst case.

Comment: You can just say quicksort. A typical good implementation has best case O(n), average case O(n log n), and worst case O(n^2).

Comment: @Gene: you are quite right. I answered too... quickly. Fixing.

Comment: Thank you !! I never tried a implementation of quicksort giving O(n) time... 3 way partition gives O(n)